# Dynamoose: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

Hi I know that the following error:

> The provided key element does not match the schema

has a few answers on here but none of them helps me as I've already applied the advice to my problem and it still persists.

I'm using Dynamoose and Koa.js for my database and backend here is my model schema:

```
const userSchema = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      max: 32,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
      hashKey: true,
    },
    hashedPassword: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salt: String,
    resetPasswordLink: {
      data: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
)
```

As you can see I've selected `email` as my hash key as it's both required and unique.

Here's my code for the controller:

```
exports.signup = async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.status === 200) {
    const { name, email, password } = ctx.request.body

    try {
      const foundUser = await User.get({ email })

      //...

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

When I make a post request with json values for name, email and password I get the following error. I've also tried `User.get(email)` both throw the same error. Here is what is console logged in its entirety:

```
{
  message: 'The provided key element does not match the schema',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2020-11-03T09:13:31.617Z,
  requestId: '63C8C3G4UU3CGOT1A96KGF8TONVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 41.812765243942465
}
```

The usual solution found on here tells me to match what I'm searching with the hash key (partition key in AWS docs). I've already done that as I'm searching by email and have set email as my hash key. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you have that table created on AWS? By default, Dynamoose won't create it for you

Answer (score 0):

According to @karjan in the comments I didn't create the table on AWS. I had assumed that Dynamoose would create the table for me but this isn't the case.